# Trouble with calling a function using two different variables

Tags: python

My question with the following lines of code is why the variable CR isn't defined. I defined the function units_covering() with the parameter CR, a variable stand-in for one of three other variables: bcr, lcr, and dcr. When I called the function, I gave units_covering the parameter bcr, lcr, and dcr respectively. Why then do I get this error:

```
line 18, in units
    raw_num = units_low + units_covering(CR)
  NameError: name 'CR' is not defined
```

Here is both the definition of the function, and its calling:

```
def units_covering(CR):
   covered = grams / CR
   return covered

def units():
   raw_num = units_low + units_covering(CR)
   rounder = round(raw_num * 2)
   units = rounder * 0.5
   return units

if now.hour >= 1 and now.hour <= 10:
    units_covering(bcr)
    units_low = (blood_sugar - 150) / isf
if now.hour >= 11 and now.hour <= 15:
    units_covering(lcr)
    units_low = (blood_sugar - 150) / isf
if now.hour >= 16 and now.hour <= 23 or now.hour == 0:
    units_covering(dcr)
    units_low = (blood_sugar - 180) / isf
print('Inject', units(),'units of your humalog')
```

It's 12pm here, so it falls under the second indented if statement. What's going on here? I called the function units_covering() with the variable lcr as the positional argument of the function...

Comment: In the same way that you pass CR to units_covering(), you need to pass it to units().

Comment: Just add CR as a parameter of your `units` function and pass it as argument in the function invocation.

Comment: The error is extremely clear - the name `CR` is not defined anywhere. Why do you *expect it to be*???

Comment: @TobyTuck You ever heard of DIYAPS, OpenAPS, and the #WeAreNotWaiting community? T1D & Hardware hacker here and your code, or at least your product (goal) is the foundation of something we have been building for a decade now. If you're not ready for all that; I would be more than glad to help you with Any Python-based coding projects that you want to create to give you more insight into your diabetes.

Comment: @Cfomodz that sounds really cool. I am relatively new to the programming world, and while learning python as my first language I picked this up as a side project. The initial purpose was to write it myself and learn along the way, but it has developed into a practical application for my daily life. I was actually inspired by the title 'automate the boring stuff' series, and these daily calculations can be very tedious. Two questions: was the product of what you guys worked on written in python, and is it open-sourced? Thanks for the generous offer, I won't hesitate to reach out if necessary!

Comment: @TobyTuck I think having a practical application, and having a personal purpose is the best way to push through the learning curve of learning a new language, or even programming in general!

The project is open source and is written in several languages due to the nature of the project (several algorithms analyzing several systems in parallel with other programs interacting with specific and even proprietary hardware (Dexcom CGM or a Medtronic pump, for example; via Bluetooth, wifi, or even directly with a radio antenna). https://openaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Please do reach out :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass CR to your units() method so it can pass it on to units_covering() method